# Dependency management and golang packages

Tags: go

We are running golang code inside a protected network and we want the golang dependencies (packagtes) to be already part of the repo that gets cloned.

That means when the golang code runs, everything that is needed is already there. And we want those dependencies to be part of the git repo. We do not want any dynamic downloading of golang dependencies.

It looks like *govendor* is one approach. *Go modules* also appears to provide similar functionality.

What is the best practice to achieve these goals?

Comment: Use modules. That's the standard way of dealing with external packages, and it is part of the go build tooling.

Comment: `govendor` is no longer maintained and doesn't work in many cases. Just use modules.

Answer (score 0):

Just to expand on the comments you got to your question, yes, use go modules, but that alone still doesn't solve your request, you will want to use modules and the vendor option that go modules provides. Then all your dependencies will be stored in the vendor folder inside your repository, which you check in and then users just checkout your repo and have all the dependencies.

Also look at the go env variable `GOFLAGS=-mod=vendor` , which you need to setup for the go tool to look at your vendor vs checking the network (I set this up on our build pipeline)

see https://github.com/golang/go/issues/27227 for a longer explanation of that env variable

Answer (score 0):

Using go modules is the recommended approach. You will have to use the `go mod vendor` command to copy the modules to the vendor directory in your development environment (where the packages need to be downloaded first obviously). `go mod vendor` doesn't download the packages into the vendor directory, it copies them from the previously downloaded modules that you have in your development environment probably in `$GOPATH/pkg/mod` or something similar, and it saves it in your vendor folder so that in production you don't need to download them. Then, you would build with `go build -mod vendor`.

So summing it up:

1. Import your packages in your code
2. Get the dependency into `$GOPATH/pkg/mod` or similar route: `go get github.com/name/project@v1.0` (this step is actually optional)
3. Copy the packages from `$GOPATH/pkg/mod` to `vendor`: `go mod vendor`
4. Compile the code: `go build -mod vendor`